# Pushing a linux binary to JFrog Artifactory using a Makefile

Tags: makefile, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I haven't been able to find anyone else who has done this. I'd like for when a build is made though my makefile that the linux binary created be pushed to artifactory.
Making a linux binary in my makefile is simple enough, and pushing images to the artifactory with "docker push" is pretty easy as well. To do the same with the linux binary, would I have to add jfrog cli into my makefile?

If there is a reason no one is doing this, let me know.

Comment: Makefile is a weird place to put it. It builds target files from prerequisite files, and an uploaded artifact is no "file" on disk. Either way Makefile has no built-in facility for artifactory so you'd have to write a shell command. Probably calling the jfrog CLI: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory Good luck.

Comment: Can I ask what your building in your Makefile? Does it make more sense to use one of the 28 existing package repo types? The other option with Makefile would be with the jfrog CLI or manually making the curl commands. Authentication will be an issue to automate this though.

Comment: It's easy enough to push a random binary to a generic repository, though for most distros, creating a package for that distro and using a repo of that type, usually then along with its designated upload tool or API, often makes more sense. Each Artifactory repo has a quick "how to upload" tab with example `curl` commands etc; there is no particular need for the JFrog tool.